# Get the difference between two dates

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am new in Sharepoint 2013 and need a little help.

I am trying to get the difference between two dates and the result should be a year. Is there a way to do this in the String Builder?

Example:

1.5.1973 and 1.1.1980 = 7

4.2. 1985 and 1.1.1980 = 5

Comment: Are the 2 dates Fields in ONE ListItem? if so you can use the DATEDIF function in a Calculated Column ``=DATEDIF([date1],[date2],"y")  see http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is simply a difference in the Years then you can use this:

```
DateTime lValue = 1.5.1973;
DateTime rValue = 1.1.1980;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append(rValue.Year - lValue.Year);
```

Note that this returns a relative difference, meaning that if rValue is greater than lValue, then the return value will be negative. If you want an absolute difference, you can use this:

```
DateTime lValue = 1.5.1973;
DateTime rValue = 1.1.1980;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append(Math.Abs(rValue.Year - lValue.Year));
```

Comment: He meant the stringbuilder in SharePoint Designer

Comment: Sorry but i didn't checked the tags for the question.